# Transform x,y coordinate space in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I know that you can transform the coordinates of a plot using `coord_trans()`, and you can even perform coordinate transformations along both axes (e.g. `coord_trans(x = "log10", y = "log10")`), but is there a way to perform a coordinate transformation that depends on the values of both axes, like a shear?

I know that I can perform the linear transformation before I pass my data to ggplot using something like `ggforce::linear_trans()` like this example:

```r
trans <- linear_trans(shear(1, 0))
square <- data.frame(x = c(0, 0, 1, 1), y = c(0, 1, 1, 0))
square2 <- trans$transform(square$x, square$y)
ggplot(square2, aes(x, y)) +
    geom_polygon(colour = 'black')
```

However, I'm hoping that there would be a way to write a custom coordinate system such that the data doesn't need to be transformed beforehand, e.g.:

```r
square <- data.frame(x = c(0, 0, 1, 1), y = c(0, 1, 1, 0))
ggplot(square, aes(x, y)) +
    geom_polygon(colour = 'black') +
    coord_shear(x=1)
```

Comment: This should be possible in principle, since `coord_sf()` does this, but I'm not aware of any current implementation. You'd have to write your own coord.

Comment: I'm not opposed to making my own coord, so I'll look into `coord_sf()`, thanks @ClausWilke

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I implemented a custom coord that does this. It takes a transformer like that produced by `ggforce::linear_trans` and applies it to a ggplot. Check it out in my deeptime package [here](https://github.com/willgearty/deeptime).